# @override of Dart code

Tags: dart, overriding, dart-mirrors, petitparser

I noticed [PetitParserDart has a lot of `@override` in the code](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart/blob/master/lib/src/core/combinators.dart), but I don't know how do they be checked?

I tried IDEA dart-plugin for `@override`, but it has no effect at all. How can we use `@override` with Dart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`@override`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/override-constant.html) annotation is an example of metadata. You can use Mirrors to check for these in code. Here is a simple example that checks if the `m1()` method in the child class has the `@override` annotation:

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {
  m1() {}
}

class B extends A {
  @override m1() {}
}

void main() {
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(B);
  MethodMirror methodMirror = classMirror.methods[const Symbol('m1')];
  InstanceMirror instanceMirror = methodMirror.metadata.first;
  print(instanceMirror.reflectee);  // Instance of '_Override@0x2fa0dc31'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

From [`@override`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/meta.html#override) doc :

> An annotation used to mark an instance member (method, field, getter or setter) as overriding an inherited class member. Tools can use this annotation to provide a warning if there is no overridden member.

So, it depends on the tool you use.

In the current Dart Editor(r24275), there's no warning for the following code but it should (it looks like a bug).

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
class A {
  m1() {}
}
class B extends A {
  @override m1() {} // no warning because A has a m1()
  @override m2() {} // tools should display a warning because A has no m2()
}
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use @override now anyway, since there is no problem with doing so and when the tools are fixed it will work. Additionally, it is useful for other programmers reading the code.

Comment: It's 2019 and the official dart playground doesn't show any warning if the method is being overridden without the `@override` keyword.  It DOES give a warning in the above example for the `m2` method though.

Answer (score 3):

it's 2021 . the override it's optional
*Use the @override annotation judiciously and only for methods where the superclass is not under the programmer's control, the superclass is in a different library or package, and it is not considered stable. In any case, the use of @override is optional. from dart api https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/override-constant.html*

example

```
 Class A {
 void say (){
 print ('Say something 1') ; 
}   
    

}

Class B extends A {
@override 
void adds() { // when i don't type the same name of super class function show  an   
              // warning not an error say 'The method doesn't override an inherited 
             //  method.' because it's  not same name but when type the same name must be 
             // overriding
print ('Say something 2 ')           



}
```

Update : the main use of @override is when try to reach abstract method inside abstract class in sub class that inherited to the abstract super class . must use @override to access the abstract method .

Comment: FWIW, I do not understand the update.